# Why the name 9 patch given to nine patch png images

Tags: android, nine-patch

I know how to work with 9 patch. But not aware of why the name is 9 patch. I can understand its 9 tiled. But what does that mean?

Google doesn't give enough and any information about this. Anyone who knows, please explain it here. It is really helpful

Comment: Well, it actually IS a patchwork!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make scalable square with rounded corners need to cut square into several pieces: 
1)left-top corner
2)right-top corner
3)left-bottom corner
4)right-bottom corner
5)top line 
6)bottom line
7)left line
8)right line
9)middle part

Parts from 5 to 9 scaled.

Answer (score 1):

Google always has enough information. You just need to know what to query. In this case, I queried for **9 Patch**:

> The 9-Patch gets its name from the fact that the overlay created
>   breaks the image up into nine defined regions, organized similar to
>   tic-tac-toe.

And a nice little graphic example:

http://wiresareobsolete.com/wordpress/2010/06/9-patches/